# Half my google search box has a black line around it that I cant change

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

[website and CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8R37.png)

[HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aq7DF.png)

As seen in image 1, the form box has a black border around half of it then goes to the desired pale grey.

Changing the color of the border does not seem to work.

I would like the border to be pale grey all the way around.

Comment: so, what is is your question?

Answer (score 0):

> It's maybe input style overwritten from other source, add below CSS to input[type="search"]

```css
    input[type="search"]{border:1px solid gray !important;}
```